# Publish changes to server from IntelliJ IDEA 11

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm giving a try to IntelliJ IDEA in order to completely switch to it from Netbeans.
I'm currently trying it in a maven+spring+hibernate webapp and it seems that for every changes in simple files html, jsp, ftl, I have to rebuild and rerun the configuration to publish to tomcat.

Normally with Netbeans I don't need to do that, it will publishes the changes to the server for me out of the box. Is there anything I didn't setup correctly or this feature is just missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the exploded deployment configuration and [Update action](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/updating-a-running-java-ee-application.html).

You can configure what is performed on Update and also make IDEA update your application automatically on frame deactivation (when you switch from IDEA to the browser).

Comment: If you don't want to depend on IDE specific features use [war:inplace](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/inplace-mojo.html) and deploy your `webapp` folder. Can't get faster jsp edition than that ;)... Although a bit messy, if you set SVN to ignore the correct paths (such as `webapp/WEB-INF/lib` and `webapp/WEB-INF/classes`) things work flawlessly.

Comment: Hello @CrazyCoder, it seem i still have to click on update <configurationName> to make that happen and have to wait until recompilation is done.Am i right?

Comment: No, as I said, it can be done automatically when you switch away from the IDE, you can also control what is done on update, either only resources are updated, or both classes and resources. As compiler is fully incremental, only changed classes and their dependencies will be updated. Normally such updates are nearly instant.

Comment: Thanks i had to figure out that the use of war exploded was key to my needs.Thanks